# get the dates of days matching b/w the start date and end date every nth week

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

Assume two dates

20/06/2017 and 20/10/2017

I have a requirement where I need to get the dates of days matching between the start date and end date every nth week !!!!

For ex:-

I get some input from UI which says, every Monday and Thursday every 3rd week between the above mentioned start and end dates

I need to get the Dates of every Monday and Thursday every 3rd week starting from 20/7 till 20/10

How can I do this?

I have written this for now

```
private static List<DateTime> Get(DateTime startingDate,DateTime endingDate,int pattern)
{
    for (DateTime date = startingDate; date <= endingDate; date = date.AddDays(pattern))
        allDates.Add(date);

}
```

which takes a start and end date and gives me the dates of days matching the pattern. For ex:- If start = 20/07 and end is 30/07  and the pattern is 2 this returns 22/07,24/07,26/07....

Comment: Not trying to be obtuse, but what do you mean by "b/w"?

Comment: @STLDeveloper, sorry its between

Answer (score 0):

here is a short solution for your question

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 05, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 21); 
Dictionary<int, string> DictionOfDates = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int weekNoCount = 3; //Every 3rd week
TimeSpan tsdiff = endDate - startDate;
int days = tsdiff.Days; //total #days in the difference from start to end
for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
{
    var date = startDate.AddDays(i);
    switch (date.DayOfWeek)
    {                
      case DayOfWeek.Monday:
           DictionOfDates.Add(i, date.ToShortDateString());
           break;
    }
}

foreach (var item in DictionOfDates)
{
   if (item.Key % weekNoCount == 0) //Check remainder is zero when divided by weekCount
       MessageBox.Show(item.Value); //prints the date which you want after the n'th week check
}
```

I guess everything in this is pretty self-explanatory, but still if you have any confusion do comment.

**Edit 1: Just explaining the concept I used:**

1. Calculate all the days between two given dates > this is our final **counter**
2. Now increment a day to the `startDate` and in the meanwhile check if the date falls in a *given day*, let's say *Monday*(I used `switch` case for this). If yes then add the `date` to the dictionary, along with the `loop #no` as an *index* to be used later. Loop till we hit the **counter**.
3. Now for all the entry we have in our `Dictionary`, if the *index* is divisible by the given n'th number of Week Check, fetch the date.

That's it!

**Edit 2: Created a method around it, like this**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 05, 1);
     DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 21);
     int weekNoCount = 3; //Every 3rd week
     DayOfWeek[] days = new DayOfWeek[2] { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Thursday }; //Pass required days here
     FetchTheDays(startDate, endDate, weekNoCount, days);
}

private void FetchTheDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int weekNoCount, DayOfWeek[] daysofWeek)
{
     Dictionary<int, DateTime> DictionOfDates = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

     TimeSpan tsdiff = endDate - startDate;
     int days = tsdiff.Days; //total #days in the difference from start to end
     for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
     {
         var date = startDate.AddDays(i);
         foreach (var weekday in daysofWeek)
         {
             if (date.DayOfWeek == weekday)
             DictionOfDates.Add(i, date);
         }
     }

     string testExample = "";
     foreach (var item in DictionOfDates)
     {
         if (item.Key % weekNoCount == 0) //Check remainder is zero when divided by weekCount
         testExample += (item.Value.ToShortDateString() + " (" + item.Value.DayOfWeek + ")" + "\n"); 
     }

     MessageBox.Show(testExample);
}
```

> Output :
>
> [image: OUTPUT]

Hope you might have got the idea by now

Answer (score 0):

This might be another way to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var validDates = new List<DateTime>();
        getDates(new DateTime(17,7,20), new DateTime(17,10,20),new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Thursday },out validDates, 3);

        validDates.ForEach(date => Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd/MM")));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void getDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, List<DayOfWeek> daysOfTheWeek, out List<DateTime> validDates, int pattern)
    {
        validDates = new List<DateTime>();
        for (var i = startDate; i <= endDate; i=i.AddDays(7*(pattern-1)))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                if (daysOfTheWeek.Contains(i.DayOfWeek))
                {
                    validDates.Add(i);
                }
                i=i.AddDays(1);

                if (i >= endDate || i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) //assuming you were counting weeks starting on Monday
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```